# How to get a IEnumerable<class> from c# in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, ienumerable

In c# I have one method

```
public IEnumerable<Office> PointOffices;

private void PrepareMap(IEnumerable<Office> tdMaps)
  {
      var pointOffices = tdMaps as Office[] ?? tdMaps.ToArray();
      if (tdMaps == null || !pointOffices.Any()) return;
      PointOffices = pointOffices;
 }
```

In JavaScript I want to get each element of Office and generate different html with attributes of Office class

I tried to do like this

```
var pointOffices =<%= PointOffices %>;
```

but it gives me error: **Unexpected token ]**

Do I need to serialise the class or the method to get it in js ?
how can I realize this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass IEnumerable List to javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520091/pass-ienumerable-list-to-javascript)

Comment: Why not create HTML element on server side, as you already have data there ? Other possibility is to make a web service for getting data and then from browser js make ajax call to get the data from this REST web service as JSON and then js in browser consumes this and adds new HTML elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to serialise the class or the method to get it in js?

Yep!

Check out [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

So in your example you should be able to do something like this

```
public string SerializedPointOffices
{
    get { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.PointOffices); }
}
```