# Accessing IEnumerable returned by a POST request on javascript side (web API)

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, ienumerable

I know that by the title it's hard to understand but I will try to explain. I have a Database of Employees, an html page connected to a script and a controller in my web api application. So, when I click a button on my html page, the relative javascript script sends a post request on my controller. The controller accesses the database and returns an **IEnumerable** to my javascript file. The query that the controller does on the database is the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Employee> Post([FromBody] string name)
{
    IEnumerable<Employee> query = Enumerable.Empty<Employee>();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        query = from e in _db.Employees
        where e.Name.Contains(name)
        select e;
    }
    return query;
}
```

this information is passed to the script. My problem is that I don't manage to access the single objects returned from the query. I debugged the code and made sure that the query returns an Enumerable of objects containing the right information I asked. On my script, I tried to access the members as:

```
$.post("api/employees", { '': insertedText }, function (result) {
console.log(result[0].name);
});
```

so the call **console.log(result[0].name);** should print the name of the first employee returned, but instead it does not. Can you help me understanding how to access properly such information?

Comment: can you provide the API response ? thanks

Comment: I guess you have property `Name` instead of `name`. Can you provide `Employee` code and API response?

Comment: you can try this: return query.toList(). Because an IEnumerable not have the value, it is a pointer. As it will be populated using toList.

Comment: I will suggest using alert to test what was return for result[0].name, I suspect it would say undefined. Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520091/pass-ienumerable-list-to-javascript, it might help you understand something, the reason propably you can't just simply pass IEnumerable back to javascript, you have to use json format for it.

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov you were right. It was a dumb mistake caused by my inexperience! thank you very much and sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Employee entity has a `Name` property but in Javascript you are trying to read a `name` property, which does not exists. You can try to `console.log(result)` the result just to see that the api is fine.

A couple of things I notice, and you should fix it:

1. Since this is a simple Get of Employees, you should use a Http Get, not a post. (api/employees?name=JOHN)
2. Consider calling `.ToList()` at the end of your query, because without it, you are returning an IQueryable, and you that's probably not what you've wanted since you are assigning it to an IEnumerable.
3. You could simplify your code to this:

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public IEnumerable<Employee> Get([FromQuery] string name)
   {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
      {
          //Return null for brevity, but you should consider
          //returning a message saying no users were found matching the criteria.
          return null;
      }
      return _db.Employees.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name)).ToList();
   }
   ```

   And for future refactoring, its usually considered a bad practice returning your Domain objects in your controllers,  e.g your Employee class. Consider creating a DTO or ViewModel and return it instead.

Answer (score 1):

`.NET` serialization creates strings for properties as they are, if you does not marked properties with attributes, which overrides the standard serialization.

So, property `Name` of your `Employee` class will be serialized as `Name` and not as `name`, and you are trying to get exactly `name` instead of `Name` in javascript.

Try to modify your script as following:

```
$.post("api/employees", { '' : insertedText}, function (result) {
    console.log(result[0].Name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable is a pointer and it doesn't have a value. If you want return a value, you must return a list.

Try this:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Post([FromBody] string name)
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> query = Enumerable.Empty<Employee>();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            query = from e in _db.Employees
            where e.Name.Contains(name)
            select e;
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: @Mikhail Neofitov was correct up in the comments. It was a problem of naming. Now it works also without the ToList cast. If you can explain me why I would like to accept your answer as correct!